# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException Building Dynamic Query Passing All Parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following sample JSON that get will get generated from a UI:

```
{
"ActionType":"LOOKUP",
"Action": {
"TableName": "ProductTable",
"Select": ["ProductName", "ProductType"],
"Where": ["productType"],
"Values": ["10.00"]
"OPERATOR":""
}
}
```

When i deserialize the JSON and try building a dynamic query using the following code it fails with: `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ProductTable is not mapped`

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Lookup lookup: lookups){           
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("select " + StringUtils.join(lookup.getFieldsToSelect(), ",") + " from " + lookup.getTableName());            
    if (!lookup.getWhere().isEmpty()) {
        for (Where where : lookup.getWhere()) {
            if (where.getKey() != null && where.getValue() != null){
                builder.append(" where " + where.getKey() + "=" + where.getValue());
            }

            if (where.getOperator().equals("AND") || where.getOperator().equals("OR")){
                builder.append(" " + where.getOperator());
            }
        }
    }           
    Query query = em.createQuery(builder.toString());       
    for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
        Object[] cols = (Object[]) o;
        results.add((String)cols[0]);
    }
}
return results;
```

If i build a dynamic query using the above approach, do i need to use a `@Entity` class that specifies the Table?

Comment: Cant you concatenate?

Comment: I guess i could do a concatenation, I thought JPA had an API that I could use to construct the query for me such as the Criteria API, however, i'm now questioning if the Criteria API is the best option or not?

Comment: Criteria API is also part of the JPA as CriteriaBuilder and CriteriaQuery, dont remember how to use thoug